# startActivity intent crashes on bitmap processing 5kb image

Tags: android, android-gridview

I cannot find a solution after surfing the web.
I have two activity classes : ImageActivity (MAIN) and ChunkImageActivity.
The other class extends BaseAdapter and it's called by ChunkImageActivity.
The first one contains three buttons by which i choose the number of pieces an ImageView should be divided in.
The second one is called by ImageActivity when one of the three buttons have been pressed.
The problem comes when an intent starts the ChunkImageActivity, that has a GridView in setContentView(R.layout.image_grid);

**1. ImageActivity**

```
    package com.example.laptop.gridsplitter;


    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
     import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
     import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
   import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
   import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;




 public class ImageActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    /*
     * Here three, four and five are the id's of the buttons declared as 
     * the contents of the sliding drawer.
     * See main.xml for clarity
     */

    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.three);
    Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.four);
    Button b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.five);

    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    b3.setOnClickListener(this);
  }

 @Override
   public void onClick(View view){

    //chunkNumbers is to tell how many chunks the image should split
    int chunkNumbers = 0;

    /*
     * switch-case is used to find the button clicked 
     * and assigning the actual value to chunkNumbers variable
     */

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.three:
            chunkNumbers = 9 ;
            break;
        case R.id.four:
            chunkNumbers = 16 ;
            break;
        case R.id.five:
            chunkNumbers = 25 ;
    }
    //Getting the source image to split
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.source_image);

    splitImage(image, chunkNumbers);
}



private void splitImage(ImageView image, int chunkNumbers) {

    //For the number of rows and columns of the grid to be displayed
    int rows,cols;

    //For height and width of the small image chunks
    int chunkHeight,chunkWidth;

    //To store all the small image chunks in bitmap format in this list
    ArrayList<Bitmap> chunkedImages = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(chunkNumbers);

    //Getting the scaled bitmap of the source image
    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
  Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,  
  bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight(), true);

    rows = cols = (int) Math.sqrt(chunkNumbers);
    chunkHeight = bitmap.getHeight()/rows;
    chunkWidth = bitmap.getWidth()/cols;

    //xCoord and yCoord are the pixel positions of the image chunks
    int yCoord = 0;
    for(int x=0; x<rows; x++){
        int xCoord = 0;
        for(int y=0; y<cols; y++){
  chunkedImages.add(Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, xCoord, yCoord,  chunkWidth,   
  chunkHeight));
      xCoord += chunkWidth;
        }
        yCoord += chunkHeight;
    }

    //Start a new activity to show these chunks into a grid
    Intent intent = new Intent(ImageActivity.this, ChunkedImageActivity.class);
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("image chunks", chunkedImages);
    ImageActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

**I AM QUITE SURE THESE LAST FIVE LINES AND THE CODE OF splitImage ARE CORRECT**

```
** 2. ChunkImageActivity**

   package com.example.laptop.gridsplitter;

   import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.GridView;

 //This activity will display the small image chunks into a grid view


 public class ChunkedImageActivity extends Activity {

     public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){

        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.image_grid);

       //Getting the image chunks sent from the previous activity
       ArrayList<Bitmap> imageChunks = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("image 
       chunks");
        //Getting the grid view and setting an adapter to it
        GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, imageChunks));
        grid.setNumColumns((int) Math.sqrt(imageChunks.size()));
       }
    }

 **3. ImageAdapter**

  package com.example.laptop.gridsplitter;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
     import java.util.ArrayList;
    import android.content.Context;
   import android.graphics.Bitmap;
   import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.GridView;
   import android.widget.ImageView;

//The adapter class associated with the ChunkedImageActivity class
  public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

   private Context mContext;
   private ArrayList<Bitmap> imageChunks;
    private int imageWidth, imageHeight;

//constructor
   public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Bitmap> images){
       mContext = c;
       imageChunks = images;
       imageWidth = images.get(0).getWidth();
       imageHeight = images.get(0).getHeight();
   }

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return imageChunks.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return imageChunks.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView image;
    if(convertView == null){
        image = new ImageView(mContext);

        /*
         * NOTE: I have set imageWidth - 10 and imageHeight
         * as arguments to LayoutParams class.
         * But you can take anything as per your requirement
         */
     image.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imageWidth - 10 , imageHeight));
        image.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }else{
        image = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    image.setImageBitmap(imageChunks.get(position));
    return image;
     }
     }

 ** MANIFEST**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.laptop.gridsplitter"
>

<application
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".ImageActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ChunkedImageActivity">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </activity>


</application>

 </manifest>


    **  LAYOUT**


       1. main.xml:

  ' <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<ImageView android:src="@drawable/katewinslet"
    android:id="@+id/source_image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

<SlidingDrawer android:id="@+id/split_slider"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:topOffset="230dip"
    android:handle="@+id/split_image"
    android:content="@+id/split_numbers">

    <Button android:id="@id/split_image"
        android:text="@string/button_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@id/split_numbers"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button android:id="@+id/three"
            android:text="@string/three"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/four"
            android:text="@string/four"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/five"
            android:text="@string/five"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

     </LinearLayout>
   </SlidingDrawer>
```

'

```
  2. image_grid.xml:

'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/gridview"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:gravity="center"
 android:numColumns="auto_fit">
  </GridView>'
```

All i got is a black screen after starting ChunkImageActivity. I doubt is a problem of processing the bitmap since it is less then 50kb image.
Can you help me,please?

NB: I used Toast.makeText previously and i noticed that until splitImage all works well. The problem comes with the processing of the arraylist or the start of the new activity.

Comment: Could you format your code s little bit better?

Comment: Yes, sorry, i hope that it is more readable now

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried debugging and checking if the arraylist is being made and passed correctly to the image adapter?

Comment: No, I haven't. How can i achieve this? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can set up a breakpoint in your main activity when the arraylist is being made at `splitImage` and consequently when it is passed to the image adapter in the second activity.

Comment: Do you mean a boolean to check if it is created?

Comment: No there is an option in the ide to debug your app. see https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html for details

Comment: debugging with breakpoints i noticed many errors related to View.java, method.java, Looper.java and others that i suppose are part of the libraries i use. Is this correct? If they have a error, my application won't work properly?

Comment: I don't think they were errors.. When you debug the app you can view all the functions that are executed after the breakpoint as well as the current value of the variables. Some of those functions belong to the above classes.In your case I'm pretty sure its an issue with the arraylist. Did you check whether the arraylist is being made correctly?

Comment: Thanks for help akash, i don't want to waste your time. I have never studied how to use logcat and it's the first time i have to do this.

Comment: I would suggest you go through some tutorials online for android debugging. It will help in not only finding errors but also optimizing your app .